# Is there a way for a parent view to detect events on a child view?

Tags: ios

I've got a view that contains a number of child views and I want the parent view to be able to respond to events that happen to its children, without a lot of manual relaying of events from the children.

Specifically, suppose I want the parent to be notified any time the user taps on any of its subviews, but also without interfering with the default action of the subview.  For instance, if you tap on a UITextView, I want the text view to become the first responder as usual, I just want to know about it.

How can I do this?

Comment: What about delegation?

Comment: Yep. I'm not sure how you want to respond to those events so that's up to you. Delegation is too big of a concept to explain it here. You can read about in Apple docs.

Comment: Maybe looks at UIGestureRecognizer to capture events without disrupting the usual workflow.

Comment: @rocky: I know what delegation means in general, but I don't see how to use it to hook events on subviews.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if by "without a lot of manual relaying of events" you mean "without NSNotificationCenter", if not you could obv use:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"subViewTouched" object:subView.tag]; 
// Where you set up tag as each subview's unique id
```

Again, not sure if you're looking to specifically not use `NSNotificationCenter`.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely use delegation, or setup your UI elements as public properties and wire the events in your view controller.  Delegation is the better route.  In my opinion, NSNotificationCenter is hard to debug and is error prone.  Use delegation.

.h

```
@protocol MyViewDelegate;

@interface MyView : UIView
@property(weak, nonatomic) id<MyViewDelegate> delegate;
@end

@protocol MyViewDelegate <NSObject>
-(void)myViewButtonClicked:(MyView*)myView;
@end
```

.m

```
-(void)onButtonClick:(id)sender {
    if(self.delegate) {
        [self.delegate myViewButtonClicked:self];
    }
}
```

handle the delegate method in your view controller

```
-(void)myViewButtonClicked:(MyView*)myView {
    //handle whatever
}
```

Comment: So you're saying to set a delegate on each subview to capture events on the subview, and I can certainly do that.  I was sort of hoping for a way to capture the event in the superview without having to do that.  But maybe it's not possible.

Comment: There's a lot of overhead with delegation (in your case), but it's easy to debug and follow.  You can use NSNotificationCenter or a UIGestureRecognizer in the view controller, but it's harder to debug what's going on and you can get some quirky behavior (mostly with UIGestureRecognizer).